# SQL count per type per hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Looking to count the number of types that have been recorded in an hour.

I can count the number of types with this code:

```
SELECT count (left (Barcode,9)) as T_Count, left (Barcode,9) as T
FROM table
group by left (Barcode,9)
```

And can count Items per hour with this code (which includes all types):

```
SELECT Year, Month, Day, Hour, COUNT(T) AS "Items per Hour"
FROM
(
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,timestamp) Year, DATEPART(MONTH,timestamp) Month,
DATEPART(DAY,timestamp) Day, DATEPART(HOUR, timestamp) Hour, left (Barcode,9) as T
FROM table
) temp
group by Year, Month, Day, Hour
order by Year desc, Month desc, Day desc
```

But don't know how to count the number of items per type per hour - meaning there will be more than 1 entry for a hour - according to the number of types there are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Year, Month, Day, Hour, 
    COUNT(T) AS "Items per Hour", 
    count (distinct T) as "Types per Hour"
FROM 
    ( SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,timestamp) Year, DATEPART(MONTH,timestamp) Month, DATEPART(DAY,timestamp) Day, DATEPART(HOUR, timestamp) Hour, left (Barcode,9) as T FROM [JCI_Trim].[dbo].[T6_Trim] ) temp 
group by Year, Month, Day, Hour 
order by Year desc, Month desc, Day desc
```

Comment: This code does return types per hour. Am now looking for number of items per type per hour...

Comment: Then you need to additionally group by `T`  and change the count to `count(*)`